# out_of_range exception in std:::erase

Tags: c++, string

My following program is giving me an `out_of_range` exception.

```
bool myProg(char* value, int length, long& num)
{
    string s;
    char tmp;
    bool retVal = true;
    s.assign((const char*)value, length);
    s.erase(remove(s.begin(),s.end(),' '),s.end());

    ...
    // modify s characters 

    std::size_t found = s.rfind('F');
    if (found!=std::string::npos)
            s.erase(found,1);

    ...
    // work on num variable 

    return true;
}
```

I checked on google all the functions and found that the exception can be thrown only by `erase` and that too only when position passed in `erase` function is invalid.

I cannot find  what input string can cause the exception as I ran it on few of my strings and the program works fine in all of my test cases.

Note that the program cannot be modified now & redeployed , to include try catch to capture input variables and check them . So i am stuck with looking at code only .

Comment: Sharing the parameters to that function used to trigger the exception might be instructive.

Comment: Complete test case please.

Comment: we dont know what parameters were passed by the caller . we just know exception occured .

Comment: If you don't know the exact input which causes the exception, wrap the function body into `try .. catch` and put print statement or breakpoint in the `catch` clause.

Comment: It is most likely that the error is not in the code posted. The exception could be bubbling up the call stack from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to change this statement

```
std::size_t found = s.rfind('F');
```

either to

```
auto found = s.rfind('F');
```

or to

```
std::string::size_type found = s.rfind('F');
```

And check that `length` does not exceed `std::strlen( value )`

Also this look logjcally inconsistent: what is the sense to introduce variable retVal?

```
bool retVal = true;
//...
return true;
```